# How many buggies, prams and strollers do we need?

Tags: travel, car-seat

We're about to have our first child and are currently getting very confused about the world of buggies/prams/strollers. It seems like we'll need the following:

- we're both avid runners, so some kind of running buggy seems to be a no-brainer. However many of these seem to be 6mths+
- a travel system which folds down and be used as a car seat (e.g. isofix)

Is there anything that does both of these jobs?

Comment: Keep in mind cragislist! You can usually easily fine the running/jogging ones in fine used condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You need two different prams** (or possibly three).

Since you're avid runners, you should get a separate pram for that purpose. They are usually three-wheeled. The reason is that everyday prams aren't meant for high speeds. Look for ones that have:

- a long wheel base with fixed wheels (runs more straight)
- big, bicycle-style wheels (comfort)
- brake lever on the hand bar (safety)

These things are irrelevant at walking speeds but essential at running speeds.

For everyday trips to the grocery store etc. a regular pram would be much more convenient, not least because it's smaller/shorter and pivoting wheels give much better maneuverability (which is *exactly* what you want to avoid when running).

- For selection criteria regarding an ordinary pram, check out this question: [Is an expensive stroller worth it?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/520/is-an-expensive-stroller-worth-it)

To really cover *all* situations, you would in fact **need three strollers,** the third being a small "umbrella stroller." They aren't appropriate for infants, but once the child is old enough to sit up on their own, these become good for situations like flights and trains, where size and weight matter more than short-term comfort. *This is where you can save money:* because these won't be used for long at a time, you don't need a brand-new, super-sturdy one with lots of features. Just pick up a used one for a few dollars. Make sure to test how small it is when folded closed.

Comment: Wow that other thread is a goldmine, thanks!

Comment: I would actually suggest a third stroller. A small [umbrella stroller](http://www.amazon.com/Cosco-Umbrella-Stroller-Dino-Camo/dp/B0035RQV8U/ref=sr_1_1?s=baby-products&ie=UTF8&qid=1326376324&sr=1-1) is handy to have, and cheap. Granted, it isn't for infants, but once a child is big enough to use it, it becomes much more convenient to tote along than a full-sized stroller.

Comment: Correct! I'll update the answer...

Comment: I disagree about an umbrella stroller in the beginning, until the child can sit up on his/her own they do not provide enough support.

Comment: @Beofett sorry I missed that, my apologies.

Comment: @morahhochman No apology needed... I realized after I responded that that disclaimer was not in the actual answer, and I agree that it should be.  I've edited Torben's answer to make sure that point is clear.

Comment: The answer keeps getting better :-)  Interesting about the umbrella stroller ... seen people with those at airports